# Check if admin has logged in

Tags: php, codeigniter

If there's someone logged in, this code checks the sessions and I can successfully view the page, but now I'd like to check if the user is admin. I tried checking in the model by Below is what I have tried and its not working.

method that checks session and if its an admin

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('authlib');
    $loggedin = $this->authlib->is_loggedin();
    ///$admin = $this->auth->admin();

    if ($loggedin === false) {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    redirect('/auth/login');
    }
    if ($this->auth->admin() === false) {
    $message ['msg'] = "You are not an admin!";
    $this->load->view('homeview', $message);
    }
    else
    {
    $this->load->view('add_view');
    }
}
```

Auth Controller

```
public function authenticate()
{
$username = $this->input->post('uname');
$password = $this->input->post('pword');
$user = $this->authlib->login($username,$password);
**>> $this->admin($username,$password); << passes the posted in values**
if ($user !== false) {
    $this->load->view('homeview',array('name' => $user['name']));

}
else {
    $data['errmsg'] = 'Unable to login - please try again';
    $this->load->view('login_view',$data);
}   
}

public function admin($username,$password){
//$this->load-model('usermodel');
$admin = $this->authlib->adminlib($username,$password);
if ($admin == false){
return false;
//if ($res->num_rows() != 1){
//return false;
}
}
```

library authlib

```
public function adminlib($user,$pwd) 
{
return $this->ci->usermodel->chkadmn($user,$pwd);
}
```

the model

```
function chkadmn($username,$password)
{
$this->db-where(array('username' => $username,'password' => sha1($password)));
$res = $this->db->get('users',array('type'));
if ($res->num_rows() != 1) {
return false;
}
}
```

Made some changes and now I get "Call to undefined function where() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecwm604\application\models\usermodel.php on line 54"

Comment: The thing that immediately jumps out at me is that chkadmn is declared with no arguments. But you'll have much better luck if you post the error message you get.

Comment: there's a lot of syntax errors, 1) `$this->auth->admin()` where did you load that library/model?. 2) `if ($this->auth->admin() == false) {` doesn't have close curly brace. 3) In Auth Controller where did you set `$res` variable. 4) chkadmn function doesn't declare arguments and it doesn't return anything

Comment: Your should turn on PHP errors in the php.ini file and see what you get u.u

Comment: Suggestion: I am not sure what library are you using. I have used Ion_Auth https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth for my projects and this is docs link http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/

Comment: @NickODell I am not getting any error messages apart from notices for undefined variables to be printed. I've added the arguments and after a normal user login I'm still allowed to view add_view. could it be my if statements?

Comment: @IsaacZepeda I'm sure errors are turned on by default in codeigniter. I'm getting notices errors but nothing serious. Besides I wasn't able to find php.ini. 1) I didn't load auth because it is just a controller. 2)There is a curly bracket, it was just a pasting error. 4) has been changed

Comment: @IsaacZepeda 3) edited, please look.

Comment: Okay, I've removed the    if ($loggedin === false) and so I can test     if ($this->auth->admin() == false) and I get "Call to a member function admin() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecwm604\application\controllers\add_employee.php on line 21"

Comment: you missed the `>` in the model when calling where method, it should be `$this->db->where(array('username' => $username,'password' => sha1($password)));`

Comment: ok that's sorted, but I'm still being let through to view the page even though I'm not logged in as an admin

Answer (score 0):

personally i will replace all your if statments and i would test it as shown:

```
  public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('authlib');
        $loggedin = $this->authlib->is_loggedin();
        ///$admin = $this->auth->admin();

        if (!$loggedin) {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        redirect('/auth/login');
        }

        if (!$this->auth->admin()) {
        $message ['msg'] = "You are not an admin!";
        $this->load->view('homeview', $message);
        }
        else
        {
        $this->load->view('add_view');
        }

    }

    public function admin(){
    $this->load-model('usermodel');
    $admin = $this->usermodel->chkadmn($username,$password);
    if (!$admin){
    return false;
    //if ($res->num_rows() !== 1){
    //return false;
    }
    }

    function chkadmn($username,$password)
    {
    $this->db-where(array('username' => $username,'password' => sha1($password)));
    $res = $this->db->get('users',array('type'));
    if ($res->num_rows() !== 1) {
    return false;
    }
    }
```